# Equivalence of Stata drop duplicates code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, stata

I am trying to transition some code over to Python from Stata. The following code is used to drop duplicate observations for the same `id` variable on the same `date`:

```
quietly by id date: gen dup = cond(_N==1,0,_n) 
drop if id >= 1
```

The below code is used to generate a sample python dataset. What the above code in Stata does is drop the duplicate observations. For example, on `date` 2014-05-01, `id` 1 has the same data in twice, as well as `date` 2014-05-02, `id` 2 etc. However, I would only like the data to appear once. Would anyone happen to know the equivalent code in Python?

```
data = {'date': ['2014-05-01', '2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01','2014-05-01',
             '2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-02','2014-05-03',
             '2014-05-03','2014-05-03','2014-05-03'],'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,
             2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3],'obs': [10, 10, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 8, 8, 6, 11]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'id','obs'])
df1.index = df1['date']
del df1['date']

df1
```

Initial Data

```
Out[1]: 

           id  obs
date               
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   2    5
2014-05-01   3    7
2014-05-01   4    3
2014-05-02   1    2
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   3    3
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   2    6
2014-05-03   3   11
```

Wanted Data

```
Out[2]:

            id  obs
date               
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   2    5
2014-05-01   3    7
2014-05-01   4    3
2014-05-02   1    2
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   3    3
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   2    6
2014-05-03   3   11
```

Comment: Why are you using `date` as an index in Pandas? In your Stata dataset it is just another variable.

Comment: I apologise for not including the remaining part of the code. After that line I do `drop if id >= 1`. I should have included that aswell. 

In regards to `date` as the index, the dataset I am dealing with is financial time series and books I have been reading recommend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create column from index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df1[~df1.reset_index().duplicated(subset=['date','id']).values]
#alternative
#df1 = df1[~df1.set_index('id', append=True).index.duplicated()]
print (df1)
            id  obs
date               
2014-05-01   1   10
2014-05-01   2    5
2014-05-01   3    7
2014-05-01   4    3
2014-05-02   1    2
2014-05-02   2    4
2014-05-02   3    3
2014-05-03   1    8
2014-05-03   2    6
2014-05-03   3   11
```